# My new grand piano sustain pedal has a small noise when activated

Tags: piano, maintenance

Recently purchased a new baby grand. Previously I had an upright. I noticed the sustain pedal has @ small noise when using at certain times. Do I need to work it out by playing ? Do I need to adjust my pedal technique?

Answer (score 5):

A small amount of mechanical noise is common, and usually easily rectifiable.  Probably not worth invoking the warranty on a new piano, though it might be worth contacting the retailer and mentioning it, just to cover yourself.

I wouldn't advise trying to lubricate or adjust any moving parts yourself, unless you know what you're doing (and, with respect, you obviously don't :-) ).  When the piano has settled into its new home and your tuner makes his next visit, ask him to have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't adjust your pedal technique.

The noise could come from the pedal pivot, or the cup connecting the pedal to the pushrod, or one of the pushrod guides, or the pushrod-action joint, all of which are best left to a professional technician to both troubleshoot and correct.  The noise could even come from the sole of your shoe on the pedal, or a creaky floorboard!